# How to install a external SSL for an ELB instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ELB instance installed on my AWS account (http://editoradbosco.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com), and it is working normally. My domain is installed on Hostgator (https://centrodombosco.org), and on this, I have a CNAME that points to my AWS endpoint (http://editora.centrodombosco.org).

However, I need to use an HTTPS (SSL) protocol. How can I proceed? I have an SSL contracted on Hostgator for this subdomain, but Hostgator has informed me that I need to make adjustments to AWS so that it works, but I do not know how to proceed.

How can I make this work?

I tried to create an SSL by Certificate Manager on AWS, appointing the CNAMES on my DNS Panel on Hostgator. But it fails. I guess its not possible to use AWS Certificates outside AWS Domains.

Comment: It is absolutely possible to use AWS Certificates with "outside AWS Domains". Post more information about the error you are getting.

Comment: @MarkB in this case, i get no erros... i just don't know how to setup a certificate for my domain.

Comment: You said "But it fails." so please describe how it fails? If you can't provide exact details about your problem people won't be able to provide detailed help.

Comment: @MarkB Sure, sorry about that. Try to load this: https://editora.centrodombosco.org. Returns a timeout error... But with http, works fine. I tried to add in the hostgator the CNAMES of the certificate generated in the ACM, it validated, but nothing has changed. After that, I removed the certificates, and tried to use the certificate that I have available in Hostgator, but I do not know how to proceed to export it to ACM.

Comment: A timeout means you probably don't have it setup to listen on port 443 properly. Is the DNS name actually pointing at the load balancer? And the SSL certificate actually installed on the load balancer? Creating the SSL certification isn't enough, you have to actually configure the load balancer to use it, and configure DNS so all requests go through the load balancer.

Comment: @MarkB ill create a new ACM certificate, and inserted it on my LB. But still loading and nothing happens. I got the CNAMES from ACM and inserted on my Domain Zone Editor too.

Comment: @MarkB i need to create something on Route53?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

Since you already have an SSL from Host Gator, you can import that certificate to AWS Certificate Manager ([instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html)). Once you import a certificate it is immediately considered validated and you can immediately proceed to configure your EB environments Load Balancer to terminate HTTPS as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html).

Alternatively, if you’d like to use Amazon Certificate Manager but for some reason the DNS validation isn’t working, or its not possible for you to validate ownership of the domain using the DNS method, Amazon Certificate Manager also offers you the option to use email to validate your ownership of the domain, as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-email.html). Once your ownership of the domain is validated you can then proceed to configure your EB environments Load Balancer to terminate HTTPS as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html).

As a side note, you may wish to consider using Route53 to handle DNS for your domain. Route53 is tightly integrated with AWS services such as ACM and, as is the case with ACM, services requiring custom DNS entries will often offer to make the correct DNS entries directly in to your Route53 hosted zone on your behalf.

Comment: Hey @Hephalump, i will try to use a ACM Certificate. I've created one, got the CNAMEs and inserted on my DNS Zone Editor. I tried to configure the Load Balancer to setup the HTTPS, but still doesnt work yet.

Comment: i need to create something on R53?